# My text in sublime text 3 has the same color

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

my all text in the sublime text 3 has the same color, for example : print ("Hello") has the same color and I want print and Hello has different colors for syntax purposes.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to save your file with a `.py` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing View -> Syntax -> Your language.

If your language isn't listed, you can make a custom definition. [This Sublime documentation](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) might be a good starting point, although I've never found a need to make my own definitions.

Comment: Thank you for answering  my question. But it turned out that I should have saved my file .py

Comment: That will make it auto-detect the syntax, which saves you from having to do the manual selection. However, if you want to change syntax, for example prior to saving your document (as you change choice of language, i.e. a .py vs a .md) it's still useful to know where the setting is. I write all types of files without saving them, prior to copying into the larger file they are meant to go into